# Chart.js - Multiple Line Charts - [2]

Tags: javascript, charts, chart.js

This question was asked, and seemingly answered [HERE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24673622/chart-js-multiple-line-charts-only-show-last-chart). Though it did not help me, or seem to even work slightly at all.

(*Using [Chart.js](http://www.chartjs.org/)*)

I use the *exact* same code as the linked post, looking like this;

```
<script src="includes/Chart.js"></script>



<div class="labeled-chart-container">
    <div class="canvas-holder">
        <canvas id="canvas1" width="250" height="250">
        </canvas>
    </div>
    <div class="canvas-holder">
        <canvas id="canvas2" width="250" height="250">
        </canvas>
    </div>
</div>





<script type="text/javascript">

    var lineChartData = {
        labels : ["January","February","March","April","May","June","July","August","September","October","November","December"],
        datasets : [
            {
                label: "Target",
                fillColor : "rgba(220,220,220,0.2)",
                strokeColor : "rgba(220,220,220,1)",
                pointColor : "rgba(220,220,220,1)",
                pointStrokeColor : "#fff",
                pointHighlightFill : "#fff",
                pointHighlightStroke : "rgba(220,220,220,1)",
                data : [160000,175000,185000,180000,185000,185000,185000,195000,200000,0,0]
            },
            {
                label: "Sales",
                fillColor : "rgba(151,187,205,0.2)",
                strokeColor : "rgba(151,187,205,1)",
                pointColor : "rgba(151,187,205,1)",
                pointStrokeColor : "#fff",
                pointHighlightFill : "#fff",
                pointHighlightStroke : "rgba(151,187,205,1)",
                data : [<?php echo $stockJanuary ?>,<?php echo $stockFebruary ?>,<?php echo $stockMarch ?>,<?php echo $stockApril ?>,<?php echo $stockMay ?>,<?php echo $stockJune ?>,<?php echo $stockJuly ?>,<?php echo $stockAugust ?>,<?php echo $stockSeptember ?>,<?php echo $stockOctober ?>,<?php echo $stockNovember ?>,<?php echo $stockDecember ?>]
            }
        ]

    }
            window.onload = function(){
</script>


<script type="text/javascript">

    var lineChartData = {
        labels : ["January","February","March","April","May","June","July","August","September","October","November","December"],
        datasets : [
            {
                label: "Target",
                fillColor : "rgba(220,220,220,0.2)",
                strokeColor : "rgba(220,220,220,1)",
                pointColor : "rgba(220,220,220,1)",
                pointStrokeColor : "#fff",
                pointHighlightFill : "#fff",
                pointHighlightStroke : "rgba(220,220,220,1)",
                data : [19000,21000,23000,25000,27000,29000,31000,32000,33000,0,0]
            },
            {
                label: "Sales",
                fillColor : "rgba(151,187,205,0.2)",
                strokeColor : "rgba(151,187,205,1)",
                pointColor : "rgba(151,187,205,1)",
                pointStrokeColor : "#fff",
                pointHighlightFill : "#fff",
                pointHighlightStroke : "rgba(151,187,205,1)",
                data : [<?php echo $northJanuary ?>,<?php echo $northFebruary ?>,<?php echo $northMarch ?>,<?php echo $northApril ?>,<?php echo $northMay ?>,<?php echo $northJune ?>,<?php echo $northJuly ?>,<?php echo $northAugust ?>,<?php echo $northSeptember ?>,<?php echo $northOctober ?>,<?php echo $northNovember ?>,<?php echo $northDecember ?>]
            }
        ]

    }
</script>

<script>
window.onload = function(){
    var ctx = document.getElementById("canvas2").getContext("2d");
    window.myLine = new Chart(ctx).Line(lineChartData, {
    responsive: true
    });


   var ctx2 = document.getElementById("canvas1").getContext("2d");
    window.myLine = new Chart(ctx2).Line(lineChartData2, {
        responsive: true
    });

}
</script>
```

I don't know if the answer/question is outdated, or if I am just doing something wrong here?

Comment: LineChartData var is duplicated

Comment: @cesarluis I have lineChartData2, and lineChartData, how is that dublicate?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

lineChartData variable seems duplicated I think you need to name lineChartData2 the second one or whatever you want.

Check this statements:

```
window.myLine = new Chart(ctx).Line(lineChartData ...
window.myLine = new Chart(ctx2).Line(lineChartData2 ...
```

Your vars declaration in each script is:

```
var lineChartData = {...}
var lineChartData = {...}
```

Two times! So second declaration override the oldest one. You need two data sets and they must match the names of the chart.js init code.

Comment: I don't see what should be wrong, one is named lineChartData, other lineChartData2. Shouldn't be a problem...?

Comment: @iversen In your posted code the two vars are named equal and one data set override the oldest set. So I think that was the fail.

Comment: What would the fix be then?

Comment: I said implicit in my answer. You need two vars one for handle each data set. in first script var lineChartData = {...}  and second script var lineChartData2={...}

Comment: That is how it currently is, `window.myLine = new Chart(ctx2).Line(lineChartData` and `lineChartData2`..?

Comment: Not in this statements, you need to change the var declaration statements wich are in the head of each script. The vars could be named whatever that match the chart init statements.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/100451/discussion-between-cesarluis-and-iversen).